# where are volumes located in apache superset containers?

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-superset

I followed the directions to run the Superset application out of a container.

After creating a connection to a postgres db in another container, I am able to create datasets, charts, and dashboards based on the tables from my db.  Very cool.

If I stop the superset container, then start it again - it's all there.  Awesome.

But let's say I want to back some all these things up...I dont want to have to keep exporting dashboards into zip files.

Is there a location I can bind against, so that i can access volumes easier?

Comment: How do you run them?

Comment: i just run them with commands, no yaml files or anything.  so, ```docker start superset``` or ```docker start postgres_db```.  but if i knew where the volumes are i would create the containers with a mount/bind or something.

Comment: Typically volumes are in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. If possible please provide the link of Superset to see how it runs.

Comment: @Saeed what do you mean by link of superset? the superset app is running inside a container within WSL...so kind of tough to share...